# WebApi Organizational Accounts - User Credential Verification Failed

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create a new WebApi project in VS2103 and use Organizational Accounts for the authentication.

I have already created as Active Directory in Azure. When I try and connect to it in the WebApi wizard click OK, I am presented with the Azure login box, so I put in the Microsoft Account details for the admin of the Azure subscription the AAD belong to and I get an error message:

```
User Credential verification failed.
Error : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name : Entity
```

Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encountered this as well. To get past it, try the following:

1. Shut down Visual Studio
2. Go to your Azure management portal, and create a new user account within the Active Directory you created (I set mine as a Global Admin).
3. Open up VS again and go through the steps of creating the WebApi project. This time, when you choose Organizational Accounts for authentication, use the credentials of the user that you just created - it should work now.

Comment: That hasn't really helped me.. When I set up a new project, and choose Organizational Accounts - it asks me to log in using a microsoft account.. I tried logging in using the credentials I created in AD, but it just comes up with a message that there's no Microsoft account with that name... How did you manage to get it to log in with your Azure account?

Comment: @ArtiomChilaru Verify that newly created user you are logging in with is part of the AD domain that you typed into the Change Authentication dialog. The only other thing that I did extra was create a bogus AD group and add my newly created user to that group - not sure if that affects anything though. Also, I'm on VS 2013.2 (not sure if that matters either)

Comment: I realised it was something else (I think).. The login window was (for some reason) only expecting live accounts.. I closed it, and another one popped up immediately, asking for my organisational account. At this point I could use the newly created AD credentials.. Go figure :)